# sending email using Gmail and Java mail API doers not send email with real name

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail

This is a sample function to send an email using Gmail

```
    public void sendEmail(String from, ArrayList<String> to, String subject,
        String content, boolean contentIsHtml) throws EmailException 
{
    try
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", EmailConfig.getGmailTransportProtocol());
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", EmailConfig.getGmailSMTPHost());
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", EmailConfig.getGmailSMTPPort());
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", EmailConfig.getSocketFactoryClass());
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", EmailConfig.getGmailAuthRequired());
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", EmailConfig.getGmailSMTPPort());


        SMTPAuthenticator authenticator = new SMTPAuthenticator();

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator);
        //session.setDebug(true);

        Transport transport = session.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setSubject(subject);
                    message.setSender(EmailUtil.getInternetAddress(
                    EmailConfig.getGmailUsername(), "jatin Shah"));
        message.setRecipients(
                        RecipientType.TO,  
                       EmailUtil.getInternetAddresses(to));
        if(contentIsHtml)
            message.setContent(content, "text/html");
        else
            message.setContent(content, "text/plain");

        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();

        System.out.println("Email Sent!!");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new EmailException(e);
    }
}
```

This sends an email using MyGmail account

I am sending an email from gmail account to another in my test

However, when I receive an email it is fine ... however, the full name of the sender is now shown

Instead of "Jatin Shah" (my name) ... it shows bhatin.shah (My Username)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read [this FAQ entry of common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

To fix your problem, use setFrom instead of setSender.

Comment: thanks ... from the FAQ .. I am making total of 5 mistakes already ... I will change my code and then see if it works ... I will approve your answer if it fixes my issues